# Как получить JSON в ответ на авторизацию

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Есть сервер, который при вводе логина и пароля возвращает статус `200 Ok`. Мне нужно, чтобы также в ответ на правильный логин и пароль приходил ответ в виде `JSON` к примеру с полем `data`. Как мне это сделать? Вот сам SpringSecurity:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint((req, res, e) -> res.setStatus(401))

            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .successHandler((req, res, e) -> res.setStatus(200))
                .failureHandler((req, res, e) -> res.setStatus(401))

            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ЕМНИП, res это HttpServletResponse, поэтому можно попробовать так

```
.successHandler((req, res, e) -> {
    res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    res.getWriter().write("{field1: 1, field2: 2}")
})
```

Comment: спасибо за идею, но мне нужно именно JSON вернуть, а не строку